# android послушивание порта после выключения экрана устройства

Tags: java, android, service, worker

Есть сервис(возвращает START_STICKY в onStart) в котором есть запускаемый при налиии локального сетевго соеденения поток прослуивающий udp порт и посылающий ответ если в порт приходят данные(простое обнаружение устройств в локальной сети).Сервис запускается из активности, имеется broadcast reciver на Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED запускающий сервис. Есть android:directBootAware= "true" в манифесте. Все работает до момента выключения экрана устройства у ухода его в спящий режим( на андроид 4.4, 7 и 8), после этого устройство с выключенным экраном перестает отвечать. Как я понял на новых версиях андроид такое поведение севисов запрещено. Как реализовать реакцию программы на манер мессенджеров - прослушивание порта при выключенном экране - они ведь полуачют данные от своего сервера. Смотрел в сторону workmanager и worker но вроде они не для этого.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У вас должен быть foreground service, и не выключаться после смерти активности

Comment: Насколько я понял в новых версиях android использование foreground service сильно ограничено - только location, camera и mic

Comment: С чего вдруг? Других вариантов у вас нет

Comment: Постоянное уведомление из foreground service мне не хотелось бы. Хотелось бы сделать как это сделано в мессенджерах, они же как-то висят в фоне. Вот я и пытаюсь выяснить каким механизмом это реализовано.

Comment: Именно так и сделано у них

Comment: Ну еще будильник стоит, перезапускать сервис